# Formal terms for a mesh over the complex numbers?

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, gaussian-integers

I apologize if this has been asked previously, but this seems to be a very particular question. For context, this is coming out of an attempt to define image pixel boundaries as a particular set of lines in the complex plane.

More precisely, I'm looking for a name/description of the following, which seems like a reasonable 'next step' from the Gaussian integers:

$\mathbf{B}[i] = \{{a+bi}$ | $a$ $\lor$ $b$ $\in\mathbf{Z}\}$

That is, this "Gaussian mesh' is just the set of all complex numbers which connect two neighboring Gaussian integers, or equivalently the set of all complex numbers where no more than one component is non-integer.

Does this object have a name? Does it have any salient properties?

Comment: This is called a "lattice": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(group)

Comment: As I understand it, a lattice is restricted to be a set of points isomorphic to the integers. I'm interested in the step beyond, where one coordinate is allowed to be non-integer, so that the set includes the lines connecting nearby points.

Comment: To be more clear, I recognize that this is effectively just a square lattice graph, but I'm more interested in its properties as a result of being embedded in the complex plane, similar to how the Gaussian integers are different from $\mathbb{Z}^2$